Will it damage the iPhone, iPad, Mac, etc., if it is frequently connected to the charger?
Will it damage the iPhone, iPad, Mac, etc., if it is frequently connected to the charger, considering ir is an Apple charger?
What about the Apple Pencil permanently attached magnetically to the iPad, charging?
Is the charger intelligent enough to not charge a device it sees is charged?

Apple has a "optimize charging" feature to intelligently delay charging to max capacity to maximize battery longevity.

No, no, yes.
I've linked your several questions to existing well-answered threads here for more details.

What's this answer!? xD
